# Как переопределить кнопку в grid Magento?

Tags: php, magento, grid

Усть `Grid` в админке, который выглядит так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно удалить кнопку `"Create New Item"` ?? Или назначить для нее другой `action` ?

Конструктор контейнера грида:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('brain_custommenu');
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brain_custommenu';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_categorylist';

        $this->_headerText = $helper->__('Category List');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = $helper->__('Create New Item');


        parent::_construct();
    }
```

Пробовал сделать [так](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-remove-or-rename-add-new-button-from-admin-grid/), но кнопка не удаляется!

Нужна подсказка:

1. Как удалить эту кнопу ?
2. Как назначть ей другой `action` ?

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто удалите кнопку и добавьте кастомную

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('brain_custommenu');
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brain_custommenu';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_categorylist';

        $this->_headerText = $helper->__('Category List');


        parent::_construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
```

Если не удоляеться через инспектор кода посмотри id, и удали по нему.
Далее добавляешь кнопку.

```
$this->_addButton('add_new', array(
    'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add Product'),
    'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new')}')",
    'class'   => 'add'
));
```

Comment: делал так! Кнопка не пропадает,  к тому же добавляется и та, что создаю :(

Comment: `removeButton` после конструктура вызывал?

Comment: да, после конструктора!

Comment: Значит id не `add` грид кастомный?

Comment: нет, не кастомный! Делал все стандартно, в инспекторе кода для наной кнопки id `id_4b36c49816574f00c993e189eef5c2eb`! Пробовал по нему удалаять, но всервно не удаляется :(

Comment: Посмотри как она в классе определена

Comment: ничего не работало , решил вопрос сделав `override` метода 
`protected function _prepareLayout()`  в нем сделал `$this->_removeButton('add');`

Answer (score 0):

Удалить кнопку:

```
$this->_removeButton('add');
```

Либо назначить ей другой action:

```
$this->_updateButton('add', 'onclick', $this->getUrl('*/*/newAction'));
```

По умолчанию id кнопки - 'add'. Если не удаляется, попробуйте очистить кэш. Если не помогло, проверьте id в родительских классах.

Comment: вы её только что удалили как вы можете обновить удалёное

Comment: исправил текст, чтобы было понятнее